Get local time from ISO8601 offset string in JS?
I have an ISO8601 fixed-offset datetime 2024-12-26T22:22:00+12:00 and I want to be able to format the datetime in both original timezone, in this case 22:22, and user timezones (I.e. 04:22 for CST)
I am looking for an idiomatic way of showing the original time using JS Library (dayjs, date-fns or luxon)
// Browser timezone (e.g. CST-06:00)
const dateStr = "2024-12-26T22:22:00+12:00";

It's easy to display date in browser time:
// date-fns
format(parseISO(dateStr), "HH:mm"); // 04:22
// dayjs
dayjs(dateStr).format("HH:mm"); // 04:22

But how I can format time at the original offset?
I was able to do this using moment and js-joda, but not date-fns, dayjs or luxon:


dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_utc);
dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_timezone);

const isoString = '2024-12-26T22:22:00+12:00';
document.getElementById('iso').textContent = isoString;

const updateTime = (id, value) => {
  document.getElementById(id).textContent = value;
};

// date-fns
const { format, parseISO } = window.dateFns;
updateTime('fns', format(parseISO(isoString), 'HH:mm '));
updateTime('fns-original', "?");

// dayjs
updateTime('dayjs', dayjs(isoString).local().format('HH:mm'));
updateTime('dayjs-original', "?");

// luxon
const { DateTime } = window.luxon;
updateTime('luxon', DateTime.fromISO(isoString).toFormat('HH:mm'));
updateTime('luxon-original', "?");

// moment
updateTime('moment', moment(isoString).format('HH:mm'));
updateTime('moment-original', moment.parseZone(isoString).format('HH:mm'));

// js-joda
const { ZonedDateTime, ZoneId, DateTimeFormatter } = JSJoda;
updateTime('joda', ZonedDateTime.parse(isoString).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('HH:mm')));
updateTime('joda-original', ZonedDateTime.parse(isoString).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('HH:mm')));
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Time Comparison</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/date-fns@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs/plugin/timezone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs/plugin/utc.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-joda@latest"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>ISO String: <span id="iso"></span></h3>

    <h4>Local Time</h4>
    <p>date-fns: <span id="fns"></span></p>
    <p>dayjs: <span id="dayjs"></span></p>
    <p>luxon: <span id="luxon"></span></p>
    <p>moment: <span id="moment"></span></p>
    <p>js-joda: <span id="joda"></span></p>

    <h4>Original Time</h4>
    <p>date-fns: <span id="fns-original"></span></p>
    <p>dayjs: <span id="dayjs-original"></span></p>
    <p>luxon: <span id="luxon-original"></span></p>
    <p>moment: <span id="moment-original"></span></p>
    <p>js-joda: <span id="joda-original"></span></p>
</body>
</html>




Please post your code samples here on Stack Overflow and not on an external site. Stack Overflow has ample facilities for code formatting and even for in-browser runnable code.

Also, please show the code that does work using the libraries you don't want to use. That will provide a clear statement of exactly what it is you want to do.

Once Javascript parses a date, any reference to which timezone it came from is gone.  So if you want to use that timezone to format the date you have to do that separately, as far as I can tell.
Example


const isoString = '2024-12-26T22:22:00+12:00';

const idate = new Date(isoString);
const tz = isoString.substring(19);
const output = idate.toLocaleString("en-us", {timeZone: tz});

console.log(output);




This is a workaround I use in the current project, but I was wondering if there are better ways to accomplish the goal without resorting to risky string manipulation.
